# Java Find default desktop application for extension

Tags: java, windows

I am looking for a way, using java to find the default application for opening a certain extension. For example, I have Gimp set to open all .jpg files. So when I evaluate xyz.jpg I want to be able to find Gimp. I DO NOT want to open the file with the application I just want to know what it is.

I tried sifting through the registry and Gimp was not the default it was windows photo viewer even though the desktop recognizes it as Gimp.

I also tried using assoc and ftype from the command line and it also returned windows photo viewer. I assume this is because it is just looking at the registry.

Note: I do not want to change the default application in the registry I just want to know how I can find what the desktop finds as the default application for a certain extension.

Matt

Comment: You can use JNA to call the Win SDK function `FindExecutable` https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb776419(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: Tried that. All it returns is a single character 'C'. I even went as far as creating a cpp project in visual studios and trying this using only native c++ and got the same result. I am testing this on a test.txt file which I default to open with notepad++

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the entries for user defined applications in the registry. HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\ApplicationAssociationToasts.

I then loaded all these entries from the registry and grabbed what I needed.